# Value changed while saving in mysql db using JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to save my records into MySql DB using JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(records). The variable **records** contains one object which holds a String as **вврвовлввв** as in Russian Language. In-memory it is holding the correct String value. But after saving in the db the String value changed to **??????**. Whenever I am trying to retrieve this String from DB it is always coming as **??????**. I want the exact String value to be saved in the DB.

Can anyone please resolve this issue?

I am using spring batch framework version : 4.1.2

Comment: Did you set properly the characterEncoding  in your db connecton string ? ie ```jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8```

Comment: I have fixed the issue by changing the value in my.ini file. At first there is only one entry like character-set-server=latin1 .... Now I have added the below char-set as well like below and it solves my issue
character-set-server=utf8mb4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing the value in **my.ini** file in MySql folder. At first there is only one entry like `character-set-server=latin1` ... Now I have added the below char-set as well like below and it solves my problem.

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
```